# can not route directly using browser url what can i do?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I cannot route directly by using input in browser.
I am using  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
so when i write the url in browser then they cannot route in angular js.

AppRouting.js

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider.
  when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController'
  })
  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'login.html'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/phones'
  });
}]);
```

so what can i do???

Comment: What do you use as web server? You'll have to configure it to redirect your URLs to your index.html page.

Comment: i am using apache web server so when i configure in apache??

Answer (score 1):

Your web server must be able to redirect your URL for it to work. 
Say you are on "http://site" and you have a link leading to "http://site/foo/bar". 
When you click on this link, you don't really go on this URL but rather on "http://site/index.html#/foo/bar", angularjs handles the rest.

However, if you directly access "http://site/foo/bar", your web server will try to find a path "/foo/bar" on your server, which does not exist, so you have to configure your server to redirect everything to "index.html".

As you're using Apache, you can use to add this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On  
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]  
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d  
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

More info [here](https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/).

Comment: this code is not use in my side   i would like to do this     when i call http://localhost/myApp/login then it will open the login.html page

Comment: Well, that's what you have to do... As I said, directly accessing localhost/myApp/login will look for a folder "myApp" containing a folder "login" containing an "index.html" (or other default pages) which, I guess does not exist, so you have to redirect to "index.html" that will load "angularjs" that will display your login page according to your route configuration.

Comment: so is not possible when i call  localhost/myApp/login then display login.html page using $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)   because without it is possible...

Comment: `html5Mode` only allows you to have proper URLs such as "localhost/myApp/login". Without this, the URL would be displayed "localhost/index.html#myApp/login" (so the real URL). That's why you need the .htaccess configuration if you want to be able to access URLs directly. So what you want is totally possible but you need to configure your .htaccess like I explained in my answer.